# Running Netlogo headless on the cloud

Tags: netlogo

I've written a NetLogo model to model agent movement in a landscape. I'd like to run this model from the command prompt, using AWs/Google Compute. The model uses about 500MB worth of input rasters and shapefiles and writes rasters and csv files. It also uses the extensions gis, rnd, cf, table and csv.

Would this be possible using the Controlling API? (https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API). Can I just use the steps listed in the link? I have not tried running NetLogo from the command prompt before.

Also, I do not want to run BehaviourSpace as it is not relevant to this model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BehaviorSpace experiment can consist of only a single run, so BehaviorSpace may actually be relevant to you here. You only need to write one short XML file (or no new files at all, if the experiment setup you want is already part of the model) to do it this way.

Whereas if you go through the controlling API, you will have to write and compile Java (or Scala) code, which is a substantially more complex task.

But if you decide to go the controlling API route: yes, that works too, and it is documented, as you've already noticed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Seth. Could you please elaborate on how a BehaviorSpace experiment can consist of a single run? I tried writing a test code that just prints an output following the Go command, with just a single repetition and a single 'Simultaneous runs in parallel'. However this prints the output twice. Am I doing something wrong? I tried entering 0 runs in parallel but this threw an IllegalArgumentException .

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question on that and including your experiment setup.